# Maximize sum(AI) for matrix A and any permutation of identity matrix I

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms

I have a random binary matrix $A$

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{c c c c c}0&0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&1&1 \end{array}\right]
$$
and a permutation of the identity matrix (denoted later as $I_p$) that will filter it. I want to find the best permutation $I_p$ (using row/column swapping) so as to maximize $\text{sum}(AI_p)$

- $\text{sum}(AI_p)$ is computed using element-wise sum and multiplication

ex.

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{c c c}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&0&0 \end{array}\right]
$$

the maximum $\text{sum}(AI)$ would be from 
$$
I_p= \left[\begin{array}{c c c}0& 1& 0\\0& 0 &1\\1 &0& 0 \end{array}\right]
$$

I am currently checking every possible column permutation of $I$, which scales terribly.

Comment: by sum(AI), I take it that you mean the element-wise sum of the element-wise product of A and I, right?  If you use conventional matrix multiplication, then AI is just a permuted version of A and the sum of the elements won't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  There are lots of fast algorithms for these problems.  How big are your instances?

Comment: arrays can be up to 100x100

Comment: Your problems are tiny compared to the sizes of assignment problems that are frequently solved.